# How can I display on html (Django project), value of date filed but, the month 3 letters

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

on my HTML file I have a value of a date filed like this : `<div> {{ offer.expiry_time }} </div>`
the output on the page is: `June ,15,2016`

June for example has 4 letters but I need only the 3 first letters.

It should look like: `jun,15,2016`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can pass arguments to the `date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
{{ offer.expiry_time:"b,j,Y" }}
```

You can see the definitions of each of those letters in the documentation linked above.